# Where's the html? Source is almost empty

Tags: html

I have stumbled across a website that has perplexed me. It has very little to no html source.

See: https://www.rebelgive.com

How is this possible? Could this be bad for SEO (no content to index)?

Comment: The source is there

Comment: It's called a Single Page App and the javascript generates the page and fills it in `<div id="root"></div>`. It's pretty common these days.

Comment: Doesn't look like it to me. If I could share a screenshot I would. Written content such as "The most affordable church giving platform. Ever." is not there.

Comment: try inspecting the page, not `show the page source` the later will only show you the initial response

Comment: Thank you. How did they do that @ZohirSalak?

Comment: first they load a pretty much empty page with only one element, then using JavaScript they request the rest of the page, check out Reactjs or angularjs

Comment: @Bainn The source is the content that the server initially returned to the browser. Anything populated client-side will not appear there. In a SPA (single page application), that could very well be 99% of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The small source that you see ends with:

```
        ...
        <script src="/static/js/2.e5b32c32.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/main.a5617d03.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look at those files, you'll see a lot more code, though it is in a form that is almost completely indecipherable by humans.

Comment: Thank you. I know it's not the right forum for this, but could this practice be bad for SEO (indexing)?

Comment: This seems like a needlessly complex way of website development. Any insights as to why they would do this?

Comment: @Bainn That is another very broad question. If you were to type something like "Benefits to single page application" into your favorite search engine, you'd likely be buried in related articles.